# Read a json data in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i want to read the value "name" or "count".

```
"facet_groups": [
    {
      "facets": [
        {
          "count": 233,
          "path": "75011",
          "state": "displayed",
          "name": "75011"
        },
        {
          "count": 180,
          "path": "75015",
          "state": "displayed",
          "name": "75015"
        },
```

This is my code :

```
LoadData(request)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);


        let facet   = response.facet_groups;

        for(let i=0; i<50; i++){
            let arrondisement = facet[i].facets[i].name;
            

console.log(arrondisement);

        }
```

When i try this i have this message : "OpenDataParis.js:43 TypeError: Cannot read property 'facets' of undefined"

Comment: Judging from the partial JSON up top you need `facet[0].facets[i]`. Anyway, the error means that at some point during the for loop, `facet[i]` is undefined. What exactly are you trying to do here? You should probably look into Array methods like .forEach() and .map()

Comment: What I want is the count value or the name value displayed. Infact, this is an array of data, so I want to grab one of that data to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it need multiple loop and to avoid error it better to use array.length instead fixed number.

```js
let response = {
  "facet_groups": [{
    "facets": [{
        "count": 233,
        "path": "75011",
        "state": "displayed",
        "name": "75011"
      },
      {
        "count": 180,
        "path": "75015",
        "state": "displayed",
        "name": "75015"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
let facet_groups = response.facet_groups;

for (let i = 0; i < facet_groups.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < facet_groups[i].facets.length; j++) {
    let name = facet_groups[i].facets[j].name;
    let count = facet_groups[i].facets[j].count;
    console.log("for:", name, count);
  }
}

facet_groups.forEach(function(item) {
  item.facets.forEach(function(facet) {
    console.log("forEach:", facet.name, facet.count)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing that your array actually starts within object index[0] and that you need to loop through the facets array not the facet groups array. If you want to loop through both I would nest a couple for loops following this example:

```js
data = {
"facet_groups": [
    {
      "facets": [
        {
          "count": 233,
          "path": "75011",
          "state": "displayed",
          "name": "75011"
        },
        {
          "count": 180,
          "path": "75015",
          "state": "displayed",
          "name": "75015"
        }
       ]
     }
  ]
  }
  
let facets   = data.facet_groups[0].facets;
let arrondisements = []

for(let i=0; i<facets.length; i++){
  arrondisements.push(facets[i].name);

};


console.log(arrondisements);
```

Comment: Your code works, but that's not how I wanted to get it. Here we get a table, I need the data inside. I got an answer below. Thank you.